# How to concatenate a character to a column based on a condition in R

Tags: r

Hi i have this data frame

```
       Table_Number.130. ID_HOUR Date   Time_.EST.
1                   137     480  365       600
2                   340       0  365       1612
3                   340       0  365       1619
4                   340       0  365       657
5                   340       0  365       700
6                   129      60  365       700
7                   340       0  365       1703
8                   340       0  365       1709
9                   340       0  365       1740
10                  340       0  365       1755
11                  129      60  365       800
12                  340       0  365       804
13                  340       0  365       811
14                  340       0  365       1817
15                  340       0  365       1825
16                  340       0  365       1833
17                  340       0  365       1839
18                  340       0  365       1848
19                  340       0  365       1857
20                  129      60  365       1900
```

I am trying to convert **Time_.EST.** field into time format but when i run

```
x[,"Time_.EST."]<-format(as.Date(x[,"Time_.EST."], format="%H%M" ), format = "%H:%M")
```

This command shows N/A where there are 3 characters in **Time_.EST.** field but works fine for 4 characters. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: What is your goal with the formatting? Readability? If so, just insert the colon yourself. Is it for doing arithmetic on the time? If so, just convert it minutes and keep it numeric. Is it for something else?

Comment: If it's about padding on a tailing `0` you could do that with `stringi` like this `stringi::stri_pad_right(c(1619, 657, 700), 4, 0)` or `stringi::stri_pad_right(x$Time_.EST., 4, 0)` in your case.

Comment: `strptime(sprintf("%04s", df$Time_.EST.), format="%H%M")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will paste a "0" on if there are just 3 characters in the column.

```
x[["Time_.EST."]] = ifelse(nchar(x[["Time_.EST."]]) == 3,
                           paste0("0", x[["Time_.EST."]]),
                           x[["Time_.EST."]])
```

Comment: i tried it earlier but it didn't worked out i dit it as `x[["Time_.EST."]] = if(nchar(x[["Time_.EST."]]) == 3){
                           paste0("0", x[["Time_.EST."]]),
                           x[["Time_.EST."]])}` Does this make any difference

Comment: You used `if`, which evaluates a single time and doesn't have an "else" built in. I used `ifelse`, which is vectorized, and has an "else" built in.

Answer (score 1):

You could pad out to a set number of digits using the sprintf function as below:

```
newtime <- sprintf("%04d",times$time)
#Make a new list with at least 4 digits: adds leading zeroes as needed
times <- cbind(newtime,times)
#Combine the two together

#A single step would also work
times$newtimes <- sprintf("%04d",times$time)
```

Then you will always have a 4 digit number to work with